# Django View Class : name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm working on the Django framework.
Now I'm making a Class for user registration like below.
I got a error on the line number 6.
Could you give some help?

```
1: class JoinForm(forms.Form):
2:    MONTH = {
3:        1:('Jan'), 2:('Feb'), 3:('March'), 4:('Apl'), 5:('May'), 6:('Jun'),
4:        7:('July'), 8:('Aug'), 9:('Sep'), 10:('Oct'), 11:('Nov'), 12:('Dec')
5:    }
6:    YEAR = self.makeYearChoice(self,1940)
7:    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email Address', max_length=50)
8:    name = forms.CharField(label='Real Name', max_length=20)
9:    birth = forms.DateField(label='Birth Date', widget=SelectDateWidget(years=YEAR, months=MONTH))
10:   loc = forms.CharField(label='Resident Location', max_length=40)
11:   passwd = forms.CharField(label='Password', max_length=16, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

12:   def makeYearChoice(self,startYear):
13:       YEARS = ();
14:       thisYear = datetime.now().year
15:       for year in range(startYear,thisYear):
16:           YEARS.append(year)
17:       return YEARS
```

Comment: `self` **isn't** defined in the class namespace (it conventionally refers to an instance, which you cannot possibly have before the class definition is even completed). Given that `makeYearChoice` doesn't actually use any class/instance attributes, why not make it a standalone function?

Comment: I'm just want to make as a class member function. and i want to know how works member functions.

Comment: ...what? At the point you're trying to call `makeYearChoice`, you **haven't even defined it yet**!

Comment: can you post your error? instead of just saying the line number

Comment: @TonyRoczz it will just be `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`... because it isn't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I figure it out. but I want to know how to make UserJoin class having member function. Does it impossible?

Answer (score 3):

This is unrelated to Django; the body of your class definition has its own namespace, and runs in the order written, so at this point:

```
class JoinForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    YEAR = self.makeYearChoice(self,1940)  # here
    ...
```

not only is `self` not defined, *`makeYearChoice` isn't either!* You could fix this one of two ways, either:

1. Move the method definition *above* the setting of the class attribute, and call it directly

   ```
   class JoinForm(forms.Form):
       ...
       def makeYearChoice(self, startYear):  # define the method first
           ...

       YEAR = makeYearChoice(None,1940)  # don't have an instance, but who cares?
       ...
   ```

   which leaves you with a redundant instance method once the class is defined; or
2. Make it a standalone function and just call it within the class:

   ```
   def makeYearChoice(startYear):
       ...

   class JoinForm(forms.Form):
       ...
       YEAR = makeYearChoice(1940)  # no fuss about self argument
       ...
   ```

I would strongly favour the latter. Also, you should read [the style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); method and attribute names are generally `lowercase_with_underscores`, and you should have spaces after commas.

Comment: Thanks! Your post is what I want to know! thanks again.